# Source file lines highlighted in red in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, editor

Don't know how, I highlighted some lines in red in a source file inside my project in IntelliJ.

- What this is used for? What's the meaning of this?
- How can I deactivate it? I tried by closing and reopening the application and didn't work

[image: marked lines in red in intellij]

Comment: Try to resent [Editor color scheme](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html). Does it help?

Comment: it didn't work, but thank you in any case :) , at the end was a little and super unnoticeable error in one of the sql statements the one that causes the whole bunch of line not to compile so therefore the highlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were just errors on SQL statements! 
I didn't notice them partly because I am more used to underlined code when errors but once solved them, red highlight is gone!